# Google Sheets - Merging 4 Columns into 1, ignoring blank data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem which I'm hoping is a pretty straightforward one. I'm sure it's from high school computing or something, but I can't quite define the theory very well (possibly data redundancy/normalisation, from memory), and therefore can't get any good google results.

Essentially I have 4 forms which capture requests. Requests can be of 4 different types, and from 4 different locations. Unfortunately due to how the location data is captured, each record has 4 columns for the same piece of info. e.g.

| Name | Request Type | Form1.Location | Form2.Location | Form3.Location | Form4.location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Unblock | North |  |  |  |
| bob | Recat |  | East |  |  |
| Jane | Transport |  |  | West |  |
| Sarah | Unblock |  |  |  | South |

What I'd like is just to have 1 column, something like Combined.Location for all records, eliminating the blank columns.

If anyone can help, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    Sheet1!A1:B1, "Location"; 
    Sheet1!A2:B, Sheet1!C2:C & Sheet1!D2:D & Sheet1!E2:E & Sheet1!F2:F 
  } 
)
```

Comment: This is amazing - thank you @doubleunart.